# Async video streaming in ASP.Net Core Web Api is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, video-streaming, asp.net-core-webapi

I have used http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/ this technique before and worked perfect for async video streaming.

But for ASP.NET Core this way is not working as expected.

By Video streaming class is:

```
public class VideoStream
{
    private readonly string _filename;
    public VideoStream(string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }

    public async Task WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var buffer = new byte[65536];
            using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var length = (int)video.Length;
                var bytesRead = 1;
                while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    length -= bytesRead;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { return; }
        finally
        {
            outputStream.Flush();
            outputStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and I have the following Action for video streaming requests:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetVideo(int id)
    {
        var fileName = GetVideoFileName(id);
        var video = new VideoStream(fileName);
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new PushStreamContent(video.WriteToStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"))
        };
        var objectResult = new ObjectResult(response);
        objectResult.ContentTypes.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"));
        return objectResult;
    }
```

Since by default Asp.Net Core doesn't have built-in Media Formatter for video/mp4 I have created the following custom Media Formatter

```
 public class VideoOutputFormatter : IOutputFormatter
{
    public bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            return true;
    }
    public async Task WriteAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "video/mp4";

       How to impelemnt  ???
    }
}
```

and added the following line to Startup.cs

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
              options.OutputFormatters.Add(new VideoOutputFormatter());
        });
```

It actually calls my custom formatter.
I doesn't know how to implement this custom media formatter for video/mp4.
Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Hi Nurlan, did you find a solution for video streaming on asp.net core?

Comment: Ji Jeyhun,
Yes, I did finally after a lot of effort

Comment: It does not work also by adding villecoder's VideoOutputFormatter code. Can you please share with me your working code sample? 
Email:  R.Ceyhun2011@gmail.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source code for Asp.NET Core really helped me find the answer to this one.  They have a [StreamOutputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Formatters/StreamOutputFormatter.cs) class that's really close to what you want to use.  I only had to modify it to look for `PushStreamContent` and it worked like a charm.

Here's my complete VideoOutputFormatter:

```
public class VideoOutputFormatter : IOutputFormatter
{
    public bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Object is PushStreamContent)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        using (var stream = ((PushStreamContent)context.Object))
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            if (context.ContentType != null)
            {
                response.ContentType = context.ContentType.ToString();
            }

            await stream.CopyToAsync(response.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of wrapping the `HttpResponseMessage` in the `ObjectResult` in your controller, you'll want to just shove the `PushStreamContent` object into the `ObjectResult` instead.  You still need to set the `MediaTypeHeaderValue` on the `ObjectResult`.

Comment: thanks for sharing but I couldn't find PushStreamContent in net core, do you have any sample or something?

Comment: @Soren unfortunately, I could not find a solution either and ended up just serving video through a reverse-proxy like nginx.

Comment: Do you have a solution ? i can not get what you have post here .I need audio streaming.